# Avoiding accidental delete of files on external hard disc

Tags: file-io

Recently I deleted my huge collection of data that I stored in my hard disc accidentally. I recovered it using some recovery software.

But I want to set my hard disc in such a way that, nobody can delete the files, even it is administrator of my system or other system , until the permission is changed.

I don't like to use any external software for my need.

What can I do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions . This isn't the kind of questions for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get to this, on Linux and OS X, at least, is setting the [sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) on the directory containing the files and changing the owner of the directory and those files to a dummy user.

```
chmod +t /path/to/dir
chown -R someone /path/to/dir
```

The sticky bit makes it so only the file owner or root (or, on OS X, someone with write access to the directory) can delete or rename files in a directory.